# problem for deploy my django-rest project on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, django-rest-framework

I have a problem to deploy my django REST app on heroku.

I have use heroku tutorial. I searched the solutions on stackoverflow and on google. I found many solutions but nothing is working.

this is my folder tree of my project
[image]

My Procfile

```
web: gunicorn source.apiNomad.apiNomad.wsgi:application --log-file=-
```

i use:

- python 3.7
- djangoREST

This is my terminal response for a command line `heroku logs --tail --app MY_APP`

```
2019-04-02T05:05:07.736659+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn source.apiNomad.apiNomad.wsgi:application --log-file=-`
2019-04-02T05:05:10.137794+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-04-02T05:05:09.767500+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-04-02 05:05:09 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-04-02T05:05:09.768230+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-04-02 05:05:09 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:48360 (4)
2019-04-02T05:05:09.768362+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-04-02 05:05:09 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-04-02T05:05:09.772911+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-04-02 05:05:09 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-04-02T05:05:09.794722+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-04-02 05:05:09 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051911+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-04-02 05:05:10 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051927+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051930+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051931+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051933+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051934+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051936+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051938+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051939+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051941+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051943+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051944+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051946+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051948+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051949+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051951+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051952+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/source/apiNomad/apiNomad/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051954+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051955+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051957+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051959+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051960+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051962+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051963+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051965+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051967+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051968+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051970+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051972+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2019-04-02T05:05:10.051973+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.052058+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apiNomad'
2019-04-02T05:05:10.053218+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-04-02 05:05:10 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.435733+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-04-02T05:05:10.450004+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302761+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-04-02 05:05:10 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302771+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302774+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302776+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302777+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302779+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302780+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302782+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302784+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302785+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302787+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302788+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302790+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302791+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302793+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302795+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302796+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/source/apiNomad/apiNomad/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302798+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302799+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302801+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302802+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302804+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302805+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302807+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302808+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302810+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302811+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302813+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302815+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302817+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.302855+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apiNomad'
2019-04-02T05:05:10.303340+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-04-02 05:05:10 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.361273+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-04-02T05:05:10.361283+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 210, in run
2019-04-02T05:05:10.361666+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.361681+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 360, in sleep
2019-04-02T05:05:10.362052+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.362055+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld
2019-04-02T05:05:10.362307+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.362314+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2019-04-02T05:05:10.362761+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.362770+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2019-04-02T05:05:10.362774+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-02T05:05:10.362776+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2019-04-02T05:05:10.362778+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-02T05:05:10.362782+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-04-02T05:05:10.362827+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2019-04-02T05:05:10.362961+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2019-04-02T05:05:10.362975+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 61, in run
2019-04-02T05:05:10.363193+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.363195+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 223, in run
2019-04-02T05:05:10.363420+00:00 app[web.1]: super(Application, self).run()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.363427+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2019-04-02T05:05:10.363617+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.363620+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 232, in run
2019-04-02T05:05:10.363878+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.364100+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 345, in halt
2019-04-02T05:05:10.364451+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.364453+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2019-04-02T05:05:10.364997+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.365003+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld
2019-04-02T05:05:10.365263+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2019-04-02T05:05:10.365269+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2019-04-02T05:05:10.365692+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2019-04-02T05:05:10.365723+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

i see that one of this error shows that my wsgi file not found but, i don't know why.

Please help me because i have no any idea

thanks